# Can we play .m3u8 file using flv.js player?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, flvplayback, flvplayer

I am working on a Live video streaming project. I am using [flv.js](https://github.com/bilibili/flv.js) in my web application to play Live Stream Videos which are in the flv format. I want to give playback option for the user. for playback, I have [m3u8](https://fileinfo.com/extension/m3u8) file to play video.
My questions are,

1. Can we play .m3u8 file using flv.js?
2. If yes. How to do that?
3. If No. What will be the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) no. flv.js plays flv files

2) hls.js plays m3u8 files.